# Nested while loop in java not working

Tags: java

user input

```
5
```

Required output (using while loop)

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25
```

Code:

```
while (temp1 <= a) {
    while (temp2 <= a) {
        temp = temp2 * temp1;
        System.out.print(temp + " ");
        temp2++;
    }
    temp1++;
    System.out.println();
}
```

i am taking `a` as input and try to form that figure but i can't.. please help

Comment: How is it not working? Is the output wrong?

Comment: Please post the entire function, this is only part of it.

i.e. you are assigning stuff to temp, but temp isn't declared

Comment: Why are you not using `for` loops? Or your debugger to debug your code?  I suspect `temp2` should be reset to 1 somewhere.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but he gave input, expected output, and the required code.  Only thing he's missing is the actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code comment below explains what is wrong with your code.

```
//assume temp1 equals 1
while(temp1 <= a){
    temp2 = 1;//you're primarily forgetting to reset the temp2 count
    while(temp2 <= a){
        temp = temp1*temp2;
        System.out.print(temp + " ");
        temp2++;
    }
    temp1++;
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Value of `temp2` after inner `while` loop will be `a+1`. Since you not resetting it to `1` later you will not enter this inner loop again because condition `while(temp2<=a)` will not be fulfilled. To correct it set `temp2` to `1` inside outer loop, before or after inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

If I have to break down the problem into simple words,

- The user will input a number: "x".
- Create a 2D matrix of the size arr[x][x]
- the value of each element will be a[i][j] = i * j; // considering (i=1; i<=x) & (j=1;j<=x)
- Print out the matrix.

There are n number of ways you can do it.

I guess using for loops would be the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int a = 5;
    int temp1 = 1;
    int temp2= 1;
    int temp = 1;

    while(temp1 <= a){
        while(temp2 <= a){
            temp = temp2*temp1;
            System.out.print(temp + " ");
            temp2++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        temp1++;
        temp2=1;
    }
```

The code above should have your desired results. Reset the temp2 variable at the end of the loop. Just change `int a = 5` to whatever you want.

Additional Answer:

```
    int userInput = 5;
    int answer = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y < userInput; y++){

        for(int x = 0; x < userInput; x++ ){

            answer = x * y;
            System.out.print(answer + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

With this answer you do not need to reset the temp variable and will produce the desired results

Answer (score 1):

```
    int a = 5; //Or however else you get this value.

    //Initialize your values
    int temp1 = 1;
    int temp2 = 1;
    int temp; //Only need a declaration here.

    while (temp1 <= a) {            
        while(temp2 <= a) {
            temp = temp1*temp2;
            System.out.print(temp + " ");
            temp1++;
            temp2++;
        }
        //This executes between inner loops
        temp2 = 1; //It's important to reset 
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Or another compact way:

```
    int a = 5;

    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    while (++row <= a) {            
        while(++col <= a) {
            System.out.print(row*col + " ");
        }
        col = 0;
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    for(int i=1; i<=a; i++){
        System.out.print(i);
        for(int j=2; j<=a; j++){
            int val = i*j;
            System.out.print(" " + val);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```